# Setting child elements of different bootstrap columns to the same height

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to set the height of these elements so that the borders with same colors in different columns are at same height.
I dont want to use javascript.
There is dynamic content in these elements so I can't use fix heights.
Cropping of text is also no option. 
I have heard about flexboxes and display: content but i dont know how to use it in this case. Who can help?

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>css problem</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .headline{
      border-bottom: solid 1px red;
    }
    .subline{
      border-bottom: solid 1px blue;
    }
    .text-block{
      border-bottom: solid 1px orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <header>
        <h1 class="headline">headdline 1</h1>
        <p class="subline">subline 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </header>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>
          text-block 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <header>
        <h1 class="headline">headline 2 - Lorem ipsum </h1>
        <p class="subline">subline - 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
          ultricies nec.</p>
      </header>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>text-block 2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
          ultricies nec,
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
          ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
          fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis
          vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <header>
        <h1 class="headline">headline 3 - Lorem ipsum </h1>
        <p class="subline">subline 3 -  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
      </header>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>
          text-block 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
          ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
          fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis
          vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
          elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat
          vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus
          viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
          Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum
          rhoncus, sem quam semper libero
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the the css. Have written some css and used it with Bootstrap classes. check it.

change the `min-height: ***px;` as per your requirement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>css problem</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .headline{
      border-bottom: solid 1px red;
    }
    .subline{
      border-bottom: solid 1px blue;
    }
    .text-block{
      border-bottom: solid 1px orange;
    }
    .col-container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      }
    .col {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .headline {
      min-height: 120px;
    }
    .subline{
      min-height: 170px;
      }
      .text-block{
        min-height: 670px;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-container">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col">
      <header>
        <h1 class="headline">headdline 1</h1>
        <p class="subline">subline 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </header>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>
          text-block 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col">
      <header>
        <h1 class="headline">headline 2 - Lorem ipsum </h1>
        <p class="subline">subline - 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
          ultricies nec.</p>
      </header>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>text-block 2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
          ultricies nec,
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
          ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
          fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis
          vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col">
      <header>
        <h1 class="headline">headline 3 - Lorem ipsum </h1>
        <p class="subline">subline 3 -  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
      </header>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>
          text-block 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
          Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
          ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
          fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis
          vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
          elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat
          vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus
          viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
          Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum
          rhoncus, sem quam semper libero
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it still does not work as expected. the red/blue/orange borders should be on same level of height. so headline/subline/textblock of each column should have the same height.

Comment: pls look at my first post. i did not want to use fixed heights cause the content can change dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Equal Height and Width using Flexbox can be achived by using CSS

```
.col-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

For further information visit https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp